# How to write custom key value in sequence file through hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am inserting records as sequence file from hive , but the key part is coming as blank while viewing file with `hadoop fs -text` command. Any way to override the key part with simple hiveql code?

The key part I am trying to provide sequence numbers like `1,2,3...` for each record.

Comment: what is your table ddl? how are you inserting records? what records?

Comment: I am doing insert overwrite to location with stored as sequence file format. Also I read like by default hive ignores the key part of a record. That is what I was asking ,is there  anyway to override the default behaviour?

Comment: update your question with the details so that someone can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

By default hive will ignore the key part of sequential file. So when we view the content of the table with select statement the key part is never shown , only the columns of the table ie the value part of the sequential file is only shown. 
However when doing hadoop -text on sequential file , the key part as well as value part is shown.

In order to have a key part populated in sequence file, we need to explicitly write a Map Reduce program.